# Running an app when the system is idle?

Tags: windows, automation

Is there any simple way to run an app or send some keyboard sequence when the system is idle?
A solution using AHK is acceptable as well.

Comment: Which OS? AHK can [detect idle](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#TimeIdle). If you're using Windows, the Task Scheduler can [detect idle as well](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383561(v=vs.85).aspx).  What have you tried already?  Where exactly are you getting stuck?

Answer (score 6):

Using the Task Scheduler it is possible to run a program when the PC is idle.

- Go to **Start->Run**
- Type `taskschd.msc` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Click **Create Task** in the right-hand pane
- Enter a name
- Go to the **Triggers** tab
- Click **New**
- For *Begin the task* choose **On idle**

  [image]
- Click **OK**

  [image]
- Click the **Conditions** tab to control what counts as 'idle'

  [image]
- Click the **Actions** tab
- Click **New...**
- Choose the program you want to open by clicking **Browse...**
- Click **OK**

  [image]
- You can use the **Settings** tab to set additional settings